# Get typed element by ID in Scala.js

Tags: html, scala, dom, scala.js

I have the HTML ID of an image element in the DOM and I'd like to get the element as an [`HTMLImageElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement).

I know about `document.querySelector(s"#$imageId")` but this returns a mere [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) which is not so useful since I need to access, for example, the image's `src` attribute.

How to I get the *typed* element from the DOM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this, is to cast the `HTMLElement` returned by `document.querySelector` and return an `Option[Image]`:

```
import org.scalajs.dom.document
import org.scalajs.dom.html.Image

def getImage(imageId: String): Option[Image] = {
  val queryResult = document.querySelector(s"#$imageId")
  queryResult match {
    case image: Image => Some(image)
    case other =>
      println(s"Element with ID $imageId is not an image, it's $other")
      None
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val result = getImage("my-image").fold {
  "Couldn't find image"
} { image => s"My image URL: ${image.src}" }

println(result)
```

---

A more general solution that works with all kinds of elements (`img`,`div`, `input`, etc) is this:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import org.scalajs.dom.document

def getElement[T: ClassTag](elementId: String): Option[T] = {
  val queryResult = document.querySelector(s"#$elementId")
  queryResult match {
    case elem: T => Some(elem)
    case other =>
      println(s"Element with ID $elementId is $other")
      None
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
import org.scalajs.dom.html.Div

val divResult = getElement[Div]("my-div").fold {
  "Couldn't find div"
} { div => s"Div display style: ${div.style.display}" }

println(divResult)
```

Comment: You don't need to do the reflection magic by yourself. The pattern matcher can use the `ClassTag[T]`, the way you would expect (`case elem: T =>`). Also, as a note about style, most people use `Some` and `None` when constructing `Option`s. `Option.apply` is usually used for Java interop (it returns `None` if its argument is `null`).

Comment: I found it useful to extend `org.scalajs.dom.document` to be able to call this like `document.getElement[HTMLSelectElement]("some-id")` using an implicit class.